# How to get the MAX value of previous group in PANDAS?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to get the MAX of previous group category.
I used DEFINE function and APPLY. But it seems performance of this code is slow. Are there other ways to do it where it will be faster?

Below is my code:

```
def Price_MAX_prev_TREND(row):
    prev_trend_count = row['trend_count'] - 1
    x = df_filtered.loc[ df_filtered['trend_count'] == prev_trend_count , 'Price' ].max()
    return x
    
df_filtered['Price_MAX_prev_TREND'] = df_filtered.apply(Price_MAX_prev_TREND, axis = 1)
```

Comment: So performance of accepted answer is faster? Timings in your real data are different like in my answer?

Comment: @jezrael yes it is a lot faster. From 0:01:06.132322 to 0:00:00.155848. Just as I thought, there is a way to make it faster. I also had problem earlier with groupby.expanding.sum, then I remember groupby.cumsum. It is also a lot faster with same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the max per group with [`groupby.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html), then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the max from the group using shifted values with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

Here is a simple example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'value': [1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 0, 5, 3, 3]
                  })

# only use sort=False if you want to keep the original order
s = df.groupby('group', sort=False)['value'].max()

df['max_previous'] = df['group'].map(s.shift())
```

Output:

```
   group  value  max_previous
0      0      1           NaN
1      0      4           NaN
2      0      2           NaN
3      1      3           4.0
4      1      2           4.0
5      1      0           4.0
6      2      5           3.0
7      2      3           3.0
8      2      3           3.0
```

If you have discontinuous integer/year/etc. groups and want to ensure that you map the previous (*i.e.* n-1) group, rather change the index with [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html):

```
df['max_previous'] = df['group'].map(s.set_axis(s.index+1))
```

Example to see the difference:

```
    group  value  max_previous_shift  max_previous_discontinuous
0       0      1                 NaN                         NaN
1       0      4                 NaN                         NaN
2       0      2                 NaN                         NaN
3       1      3                 4.0                         4.0
4       1      2                 4.0                         4.0
5       1      0                 4.0                         4.0
6       2      5                 3.0                         3.0
7       2      3                 3.0                         3.0
8       2      3                 3.0                         3.0
9       4      7                 5.0                         NaN
10      4      3                 5.0                         NaN
11      4      1                 5.0                         NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

First aggregate max values by [`GroupBy.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) and then create new column by mapping with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by previous trend - add `1` to indices (from `trend_count` column), `sort=False` is used for improve performance:

```
s = df.groupby('trend_count', sort=False)['Price'].max()
df['Price_MAX_prev_TREND'] = df['trend_count'].map(s.rename(lambda x: x+1))
```

Another idea is add `1` to `trend_count` before aggregate `max`:

```
s = df.assign(trend_count = df['trend_count'].add(1)).groupby('trend_count', sort=False)['Price'].max()
df['Price_MAX_prev_TREND'] = df['trend_count'].map(s)
```

Performance depends of data, best test in real data:

```
np.random.seed(2023)
N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'trend_count':np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                   'Price': np.random.randint(1000, size=N)})
```

---

```
#original solution
In [192]: %%timeit
     ...: df['Price_MAX_prev_TREND1'] = df.apply(Price_MAX_prev_TREND, axis = 1)
     ...: 
     ...: 
     ...: 
4.02 s ± 197 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [193]: %%timeit
     ...: s = df.groupby('trend_count', sort=False)['Price'].max()
     ...: df['Price_MAX_prev_TREND'] = df['trend_count'].map(s.rename(lambda x: x+1))
     ...: 
     ...: 
2.38 ms ± 22.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [194]: %%timeit
     ...: s = df.assign(trend_count = df['trend_count'].add(1)).groupby('trend_count', sort=False)['Price'].max()
     ...: df['Price_MAX_prev_TREND'] = df['trend_count'].map(s)
     ...: 
     ...: 
2.26 ms ± 16.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#mozway solution
In [195]: %%timeit
     ...: s = df.groupby('trend_count', sort=False)['Price'].max()
     ...: df['max_previous'] = df['trend_count'].map(s.set_axis(s.index+1))
     ...: 
3.01 ms ± 340 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```